# Add parameter on redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling to add a parameter to a URL when a button is clicked.
So, in PAGE 1 when a button is clicked, it'd redirect to PAGE 2 and add a parameter to the URL of PAGE 2

The parameter should be the last part of the PAGE 1 url:

PAGE 1 url: page.com/page1/food -> food should be the parameter added to PAGE 2 on button click

PAGE 2 url: page.com/page2   -> Add parameter to this URL

I've been trying to do this, but I can't figure out how to pass the param from PAGE 1 to PAGE 2 on button click

Comment: Can you provide the code you've tried so far

Comment: Could you amend the URL structure? It makes the most sense to put the page last, so `page.com/food/2`, then it's trivial to amend.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan PAGE 2 is another part of the website with lots of child pages on it, that's why it can't be moved under PAGE 1

Comment: can't you just use an anchor?

Comment: `<a href="page.com/page2/food">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.location.href` to get the current URL of the page you're on. This will be stored as a string. You can then use `.split('/')` to turn your string into an array of parameters (where each index is split based on a `/`).

Eg:

`"page.com/page1/food".split('/')`

will yield:

`const params = ["page.com", "page1", "food"]`

To get the last element of this array you can use `params.length-1` as the index, and then append this retrieved value onto the end of your redirected page. To redirect you set `window.location.href` equal to the new url.

See working example below:

```js
$('#redirect').click(function() {
  const url = window.location.href; // 'https://stacksnippets.net/js'
  const params = url.split('/'); // ['https', '', 'stacksnippets.net', 'js']
  const parameter = params[params.length-1]; // 'js'
  
  const page2 = "https://www.example.com/" +parameter; // 'https://www.example.com/js'
  alert("Going to new page: " +page2);
  window.location.href = page2 // Go to page2 url
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="redirect">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the URL via JS very easily.

You have not provided the button click code in the question. So I am assuming there can be two ways to be redirected to another page;

1. You can add a button and write a click function to redirect;

   ```
   <button onclick="redirect()"> Go To Page 2 </button>
   <script>
   function redirect()
   {
       var currentUrl = window.location.href;
       var parts = currentUrl.split("/");
       var param = parts[parts.length() -  1];
       window.location.hef = page2_url + "/" + param;
   }
   </script>
   ```
2. You can also add an anchor tag for redirection;

   ```
   <a href="page2_url" id="redirectlink"> Button </a>
   <script>
     (function(){
         var currentUrl = window.location.href;
         var parts = currentUrl.split("/");
         var param = parts[parts.length() -  1];

         $("#redirectlink").attr("href", "page2_url" + "/" + param)
    })()
   </script>
   ```